# Why is my XAML button PointerOver VisualState not working?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, visualstates

I am trying to get the following `PointerOver` VisualState to work. Ideally when the mouse pointer is over the button, I want to highlight the button with a black border.

I have been trying various ways to make this work, please help.

Note: If I set the BorderColor value of the BorderHighlight, Border element, I get the border desired, but not when I made it as part of the VisualState.

```
<Style x:Key="SecondaryButton"  TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ButtonHighlight" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="innerRectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Transparent" 
                                   StrokeThickness="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                   RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15"   />

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Text" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="0" Duration="1"></ColorAnimation>
                                            <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="LightSkyBlue" Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="0" Duration="1"></ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"  Duration="0:0:1"></ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                           .
                                           .
                                           .
```

I snipped the extraneous code to keep the question short and to the point, but this all compile, just not getting the result desired. I could also use 2 rectangles (one smaller than the other), but would like to make it work with actual border.

Additionally what would be the difference between targeting:

```
   <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="Black" 
   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonHighlight"   
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"         
   Duration="0:0:1"></ColorAnimation>
```

and

```
   <ColorAnimation From="Transparent" To="Black" 
   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonHighlight" 
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
   Duration="0:0:1"></ColorAnimation>
```

Answer (score -1):

The VisualState is called "MouseOver", not "PointerOver"

Comment: Where did you get "MouseOver" from?

Comment: Hmm... http://snag.gy/4Skk4.jpg... it's probably different with Windows 8... sorry, then